# How to link stacks to other stacks using Linked List in C programming?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I made my own stack using linked list. But I think this is wrong.
my push method is linking Stack1 to other stacks.
So, I think it is like...

```
In my main function,

push(stack1, 10);
push(stack1, 20);

[Stack1] -> [nextStack]
[Stack1] -> [nextStack] (new address from first nextStack)
```

So, It's like... I am repeating to link stack1 to other stacks again and again...

this is my stack using linked list code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int data;
   struct stack *top;
}stack;

void push(stack *currentStack, int data){

    if (currentStack->top == NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack is emtpy");

    else{
        stack *nextStack = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
        currentStack->data = data;
        currentStack->top = nextStack;

        printf("currentStack is %d\n", currentStack->data);
    }
}

int main(){

    stack* stack1;
    stack1 = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));

    push(stack1, 10);
    push(stack1, 20);

    return 1;
}
```

and this is the result of my code.

```
currentStack is 10
currentStack is 20
```

Comment: At least you never initialize the struct you allocate so you’ll get undefined behavior when you use it. Using a debugger would show you this immediately, so do learn how to use one from the beginning.

Comment: @ Sami Ok. I feel I don't have any basics of it.  really thanks. I will look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack
{
    int data;
    struct stack *top;
}  *head = NULL;


void push(int data)
{
    if (head == NULL)   //that means stack is empty
    {
        head =(struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
        head->top = NULL;
        head->data = data;
    }
    else
    {
        temp =(struct node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
        temp->top = head;
        temp->data = data;
        head = temp;
    }

}
```

Your ***push()*** function is incomplete.
It should consider two cases one when stack is empty and one when it is not.

Also there is no need to pass a **pointer-to-stack** in *push()* function because push() function by default pushes the new element on the topmost node and there is only one stack.

Also you have not initialised your stack pointer with **NULL**. This might give you undefined behaviour during program run.

Comment: "Also there is no need to pass a pointer-to-stack in push() function because push() function by default pushes the new element on the topmost node and there is only one stack." - Even if in a particular application, only one stack was required, designing a data structure as one single global data structure is inflexible and fosters all kinds of errors. NEVER design data structures as single globals!

Comment: On the bright side, your code should works. I guess it would be helpful to at least mention the actual cause of failure in the original code: That the stack contained one element at most and each push() just overwrote the old element in the stack (well, dropped it creating a mem leak...). Regarding: "Your push() function is incomplete. It should consider two cases one when stack is empty and one when it is not." - Yes, it is?